# No F & P values for main effects in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova, linguistics, phonetics

I'm running repeated-measures ANOVAs using `aov` in R, and all variables are within-subjects.
But R is not showing main effects. Several people have looked at my code, and no one knows why. It looks like:

```
test1 = aov(y ~ (a*b+c) + Error(Subject/a*b+c), mydata))
```

But when I run `summary(test1)`, I only get one P value:

```
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
a:b           4 431859  107965   2.637  0.185
```

For main effects `a, b, c` I am only getting `Df Sum Sq Mean Sq`.

I *also* tried switching to `"afex"`, and doing this:

```
test1 <- aov_ez("Subject", "y", mydata, within = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

But *then* the summary does not allow me to do a complex interaction, like `a*b+c`. Not all variables interact in my model. I need two to interact, but I have to control for the main effect of the other.

Comment: It may well be due to confounding/aliasing in your data.  Can you `dput()` all or part of your input?

Comment: I am not really sure `Error(Subject / a * b + c)` makes sense. Generally, `Error(Subject / x * y)` would describe two crossed within-subject factors `x` and `y` (or more explicitly: it corresponds to a within-subject predictor `x` that is crossed with another within-subject predictor `y`). I'm not sure what `Error(Subject / x + y)` is supposed to describe in a within-subject design. I don't understand what you mean by "[n]ot all variables interact in my model". Is this an issue concerning crossed and nested predictors?

Comment: Thank you for your input, guys.
Today I found out we are probably running the wrong type of ANOVA (Type II instead of I or III).
Maurits, I think you're right that the error term is incorrect. I do not have enough stats training for this project.